# Javascript passing parameter with arrow function

Tags: javascript

I have a class for creating a jquery datatable, it works but I'm having some issue with the following piece of code:

```
 let table = $("#" + this.name).DataTable();
 table.on( 'click', 'tr td.details-control', function() {
        let detailRows = [];
        let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        let row = table.row( tr );
        let idx = $.inArray( tr.attr('id'), detailRows );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            tr.removeClass( 'details' );
            row.child.hide();

            detailRows.splice( idx, 1 );
        }
        else {
            tr.addClass( 'details' );
            let rowData = table.row(tr).data();
            row.child(this.formatChildRows( rowData ) ).show();

            if ( idx === -1 ) {
                detailRows.push( tr.attr('id') );
            }
        }
    } );
```

Because of the way "this" works in javascript, the function formatChildRows is no longer found as this no longer refers to the class but to the table row, I solved this by changing the code like so:

```
table.on( 'click', 'tr td.details-control', (event) => {
    ...
} );
```

The function now runs but the "table" variable is no longer accessible as it is undefined in the arrow function.

I tried plenty of things like:

```
evt => function(table) {}
```

instead of:

```
(event) =>
```

I thought this might work but the code inside the function is no longer being executed for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you supersede it with something like `(table) =>` or `var table` within the callback, or change its value after the fact `table` should continue to refer to the original `table` value. Can you show us a complete example of some code where this isn't working?

Comment: `The function now runs but the "table" variable is no longer accessible as it is undefined in the arrow function.` -> NO?!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const self = this;
table.on( 'click', 'tr td.details-control', function (event){
    row.child(self.formatChildRows( rowData ) ).show();
    ...
} );
```

But if it is possible you should avoid `this` keyword, for example you should refer directly to object `objectName.formatChildRows()`.